# ERP: Database Designing Approach

Tags: sql, database, database-design, erp

Stuck on Some Design Patterns. Is there any guidance on designing database for ERP application?? A Book or something else?? Since this is a huge application Would like to start out with a good approach rather than coming back later to right the wrongs!!

I have on my part initially have identified entities and tried forming relations and getting stuck on some part or other!
For e.g
If A Single Product has multiple vendors
Say 2 pcs of ProductA purchased from vendorA @ 10 bucks each 
and 1 pcs of ProductA purchased from vendorB @ 20 bucks

Now, a client order 3pcs of ProductA and after delivery returns 1pc out of 3 ordered.
How to remap the returned piece to either from vendorA  or vendorB

cz if this is not done then how will the finances will be managed at the end of the year to show total list of expenses, profit etc!!

Answer (score 4):

This is hard to answer because everyone's needs are different. However, something that helped me immensely was researching the convergence between ERP and database design.

[This resource titled Flexible Database Design for ENTERPRISE RESOURCE PLANNING (ERP) APPLICATIONS,](http://www.academia.edu/3161344/Flexible_Database_Design_for_ENTERPRISE_RESOURCE_PLANNING_ERP_APPLICATIONS)  goes into great detail on just about anything you may need to know about ERP and database design.

Past that, there's nothing more we can give currently because the question is broad. Best of luck

Comment: hey, thanks for the response. Can you give a solution to the query that i have mentioned in the 2nd part of this question. The order part.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon this trying to figure out something similar and I think I might have a solution to the second part of your question.

It all comes down with how you treat your inventory (this is more of an accounting concept). There are many ways but the two basic I can think of are FIFO (First in First out), and FILO (First in Last out).

FIFO means that the first item to arrive in inventory, is the first item that is sold (ie: to leave inventory). FILO means that the first item to arrive in inventory is the last item sold.

So in your example if you are using FIFO, the return would be remapped to Vendor B because it was the last one purchased. If you were using FILO it would be remapped to Vendor A.

I'm a little rusty on my inventory accounting and I'm sure there are better explanations out there, but hopefully this might put you on the right track.